# How to open/view/import .dbf file in jetbrains datagrip?

Tags: datagrip, intellij-datagrip

How do I work with .dbf files in Jetbrains DataGrip ?
I am on macos and need to work with .dbf file. I managed to open dbf file in Shapefile explorer software. But I would like to use cool features DataGrip offering. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

done with `shp2pgsql`

for example:

```
shp2pgsql -s 4326 -g geom_4326 "file_name" schema.table | psql -h localhost -p 5432 -d database -U user
```

Answer (score 4):

I use [`dbf-to-sqlite`](https://pypi.org/project/dbf-to-sqlite/) Python package - pretty straightforward way to discover DBF structure and data inside. It creates SQLite database which supported by DataGrip out of the box.

```
pip install dbf-to-sqlite
dbf-to-sqlite PIndx01.dbf post_index.sqlite
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do that and even there is no ticket in the tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/DBE

Comment: one way could be to convert dbf to csv and then impor csv into database with datagrip